# Cannot install GLPK in canopy

Tags: python, enthought

I am using Enthought's Canopy academic version and Windows 7 64-bit. After successfully installing PulP in canopy, I've been trying to install LP/GLPK to solve MIP problems in python, and I cannot figure out how to install it properly.

I first download GLPK from http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/ and unzip it in my computer. Then I wrote `pip install glpk`in Canopy Command Prompt. Then I have an error message

```
error: Could not find Visual Studio 2008 in your path.
```

However, I have Visual Studio 2008 already. In case, I installed mingw by following the instruction
    To install mingw, do: enpkg mingw

However, I still get the same error message.

I've tried everything I could figure out from online, but I m stuck. Any tips and advice would be very appreciative.